# Diffuse does not works with glib on MacOS 10.7

Tags: macos, installation, diff

I'm trying to install Diffuse comparison software using MacPort.
It was installed, but can't be run.

```
[15:16:18]~$ export LANG=C; export LC_ALL=C
[15:38:48]~$ diffuse 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/diffuse", line 159, in <module>
    gtk.window_set_default_icon(gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(iconpath))
glib.GError: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/opt/local/bin/../share/pixmaps/diffuse.png'
```

I've got same result using source file.

My system parameters:

```
OSX 10.7.4
gcc 4.6.3
```

Please, help me to find the reason.

Comment: export LANG=C; export LC_ALL=C

Comment: Paulo Scardine, and what does it do?

Comment: `export LANG=C; export LC_ALL=C` fixes the "unknown locale" error under OSX. Seems like your build lacks support for png images, perhaps you should install some prerequisites before diffuse - just a guess, do you have something like libpng installed?

Comment: Yes. [16:38:23]~$ port installed | grep libpng
  libpng @1.4.12_0 (active)

Comment: Installing libpng is not the same as building GLib with PNG support. Have you verified that the file at that path is a valid PNG? If so, then it looks like whatever version of GTK you have on your system doesn't support PNG images.

Comment: jmk, It does exists. And how to make the system support PNG?